# Persisting objects to other table when persisting object

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to create multiple clientroles when creating a client. These roles are saved in the clientstructure table where each role per client has is own entry.  I want the roles to be created when i create a new client. On default all roles are owned by the new client. When i try to persist the client id to the database (foreign key) it gives this error:

*An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO clientstructure (role, clientid, roleowner) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["Client", null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'clientid' cannot be null*

My code:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ClientType', $client);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($client);
        $roles = ['Client', 'Invoice receiver', 'Payment maker', 'Location'];

        foreach ($roles as $role) {

            $clientstructure = new Clientstructure();
            $clientstructure->setClientid($client->getClientid());
            $clientstructure->setRole($role);
            $clientstructure->setRoleowner($client->getClientid());
            $em->persist($clientstructure);
        }

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('client_show', array('clientid' => $client->getClientid()));
    }

    return $this->render('client/new.html.twig', array(
        'client' => $client,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: `$clientstructure->setClientid($client->getClientid());` - Your client doesn't have an id (so this returns `null`) at that point since it's not in the database. It's merely **scheduled** to be persisted. You should use an association and simply set that (eg. `setClient($client)`).

Comment: `setClientid` - Doctrine is about entities, not Ids. You should add another related entity, instead of setting foreign key manually.

Comment: How do i add another related entity?

Comment: See [Doctrine Docs: Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)